# Dynamically add options to option group at particular location

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a small query. I would like to have a HTML  select in my page having structure:

```
<select id="selectedFormulae">
    <option value="0" disabled="" selected="">select</option>
    <optgroup label="Box1">
        <option value="1">Formula1</option>
        <option value="2">Formula2</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Box2?">
        <option value="1">Formula1</option>
        <option value="2">Formula2</option>
        <option value="3">Formula3</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Marital status?">
        <option value="1">Formula1</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

The options of the select will be added as per what user adds in his computations. My question here is how do I add particular option under particular option group? ie. if user adds another value under box1 then new option should be added under `<optgroup label="Box1">` like this:

```
<optgroup label="Box1">
    <option value="1">Formula1</option>
    <option value="2">Formula2</option>
    <option value="3">Formula3</option>
</optgroup>
```

Same way if user deleted some value say Formula2 of Box1 then  it will have only this:

```
<optgroup label="Box1">
    <option value="1">Formula1</option>
    <option value="3">Formula2</option>
</optgroup>
```

I was planning to save all the options in JSON object and then modifying the select html as per what user adds in. Any help with this?

I tried adding it to jsonobject like this:

```
var opt = {
    Box1:[
        {name:"Formula1"},
        {name:"Formula2"}
    ],
    Box2:[
        {name:"Formula1"},
        {name:"Formula2"}
    ],
    Box3:[
        {name:"Formula1"},
        {name:"Formula2"}
    ]
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this: you can use jQuery attribute selector to find a particular option group and append new option to it

```
$("#selectedFormulae").find('optgroup[label="Box1"]').append('<option>New option</option>');
```

Here option group with `label="Box1"` get selected and user can append new option to it, similarly, user can delete option using below code

```
$("#selectedFormulae").find('optgroup[label="Box1"]').find('option').filter(function(){
    var text = $(this).text();
    return text=='New option'; 
}).remove();
```

**EDIT** - to know if an option exists already, use below code

```
var $optionGroup = $("#selectedFormulae").find('optgroup[label="Box1"]');
var optionLength = $optionGroup.find('option').filter(function(){
    return $(this).text() == "New option";
);

if(optionLength.length < 1) //option does not exist
{
    $optionGroup.append('<option>New option</option>');
}
```

Comment: is there a way to check if new value to be inserted already exists before appending a new value?

Comment: I would add a value attribute to option tag so that I could check if that value option is already there in option group then delete existing and add new one (or edit existing option with new text) else directly add new option

Answer (score 1):

it can be achieve by your jsonobject :

```
 var opt = {
        Box1:[
            {name:"Formula1"},
            {name:"Formula2"}
        ],
        Box2:[
            {name:"Formula1"},
            {name:"Formula2"}
        ],
        Box3:[
            {name:"Formula1"},
            {name:"Formula2"}
        ]
    };

    $(function(){
        var $select = $('#mySelect');
        $.each(opt, function(key, value){
            var group = $('<optgroup label="' + key + '" />');
            $.each(value, function(){
                $('<option />').html(this.name).appendTo(group);
            });
            group.appendTo($select);
        });
    });
```

here the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ZP4E9/29/